# Could not fetch all href link using BeautifulSoup module using python2.7

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi i am using following python code to get all the url links from the webpage :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url='https://www.practo.com/delhi/dentist'
resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print link['href']
```

But the above code not able to fetch all the links, as you can see below only few links :

```
https://www.practo.com
/health/login
/for-doctors
javascript:void(0);
#
http://help.practo.com/practo-search/practo-relevance-algorithm
http://help.practo.com/practo-search/practo-ranking-algorithm
https://www.practo.com/delhi/clinic/prabhat-dental-care-shahdara?subscription_id=416433&specialization=Dentist&show_all=true
https://www.practo.com/delhi/clinic/prabhat-dental-care-shahdara?subscription_id=416433&specialization=Dentist&show_all=true
https://www.practo.com/delhi/clinic/prabhat-dental-care-shahdara#services
https://www.practo.com
/health/login
/for-doctors
javascript:void(0);
#
http://help.practo.com/practo-search/practo-relevance-algorithm
http://help.practo.com/practo-search/practo-ranking-algorithm
https://www.practo.com/delhi/clinic/prabhat-dental-care-shahdara?subscription_id=416433&specialization=Dentist&show_all=true
https://www.practo.com/delhi/clinic/prabhat-dental-care-shahdara?subscription_id=416433&specialization=Dentist&show_all=true
https://www.practo.com/delhi/clinic/prabhat-dental-care-shahdara#services
```

Please someone can help me why its happening, is there any other method through which i can able to scrap all thee links.... thanks in advance

Comment: What other links do you want to grab?

Comment: There are approx 500 url links which i could not grab with above method

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
import urllib2
import re

url='https://www.practo.com/delhi/dentist?page=1'
resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
s = resp.read()
regexp = r'http[^"]*"'
pattern = re.compile(regexp)
urls = re.findall(pattern, s)
for i in urls:
    print i
```

Comment: Thanks for answering , but this also i have already tried . does not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

This shall return all the `http` links in that website:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url='https://www.practo.com/delhi/dentist'
resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp)
for i in soup.findAll('a',href = True):
    link = i['href']
    if link[:4] == 'http':
        print link
```

Comment: Thanks for answering , but this also i have already tried . does not work :-(

Comment: Do you have `Beautifulsoup` library?  Not `Beautifulsoup4`. Check it out please.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and was able to fix it by changing the parser used with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc) from `lxml` to `html.parser`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import http.server

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
try:
  with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
  html = response.read()
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
  errorMsg = http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.responses[e.code][0]
  print("Cannot retrieve URL: {} : {}".format(str(e.code), errorMsg))
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
  print("Cannot retrieve URL: {}".format(e.reason))
except:
  print("Cannot retrieve URL: unknown error")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
  print("Link: {}".format(link['href']))
```

You can read more about the different parser in the documentation under [Installing a parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).